# many-to-many mandatory relationship enforce mandatory value

Tags: database, hibernate, powerdesigner

I have a **many-to-many** relationship, and one direction is **mandatory**, like the following diagrams, conceptual model and physical model. A **UserAccount** has to have one or more **Permission** to it. When we insert a **UserAccount**, how can we **enforce** at least one Permission is assigned to it? This enforcement should be **in database** or in our **client code**? I will use **Hibernate**.

I am using PowerDesigner for this modeling and it generated the database sql for me and it looks like there is no such constraint for insert. If PowerDesigner can help, how to do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I don't think it can be generated automatically by PowerDesigner.

Comment: To ensure the integrity of the database, you can add an insert trigger on UserAccount to verify that there exists a related Permission; and a delete trigger on UserAccount_Permission to verify that it does not leave a UserAccount without Permission... The problem is that triggers would have to be trigger at commit-time, if supported by your database. **Else** you have an insertion problem: you cannot insert a UserAccount without UserAccount_Permission, but you cannot insert a UserAccount_Permission without the referenced UserAccount...

Comment: I am using MariaDB or MySQL database.